# Problemas ao utilizar getJSON para carregar Json da página php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

A inteção é pegar o resultado de um select, atribuir em um array, e colocar o seu valor em um elemento html.
o valor é listado e atribuído ao array, porém, não consigo inserir ele no meu html
meu jquery que efetua isso

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("tr[data-toggle='modal']").click(function(){

        //Pegando valores dos campos "data-* do <tr> clicado"
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var data = $(this).data("data");
        var status = $(this).data("status");
        var problema = $(this).data("problema");
        var solucao = $(this).data("solucao");
        var carro = $(this).data("carro");
        var cpf = $(this).data("cpf");

        //requisição ajax para obter dados das tabelas "cliente" e "veículo"
        $.getJSON('../controller/php/carregar_dados_OS_Modal.php?search=',{id_carro: carro, ajax: 'true'}, function(resultado)
            {
            $("#nome_cliente").text(resultado.nome_cliente);
            });


        //Atribuindo esses valores aos elementos do modal
        $("#id").text("ID Ordem de serviço #"+id);
        $("#data").text("Emissão: "+data);
        $("#status").val(status);
        $("#problema").text(problema);
        $("#solucao").text(solucao);

        });
    });
</script>
```

php para a listagem:

```
$id_veiculo = $_REQUEST['id_carro'];
$cpf = "25836914766";

$conn = new Conexao();
$link = $conn->getLink();

$select = "SELECT veiculo.PLACA , veiculo.NOME as NOME_VEICULO,cliente.NOME as NOME_CLIENTE,cliente.TELEFONE FROM `veiculo` INNER join cliente on veiculo.CPF = cliente.CPF WHERE cliente.CPF =$cpf AND veiculo.ID_CARRO =$id_veiculo ";
$resultado_consulta = mysqli_query($link, $select);

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_consulta) )
{
 echo $row['NOME_CLIENTE'];
 echo "<BR>";
 echo $row['NOME_VEICULO'];
 echo "<BR>";
 echo $row['TELEFONE'];
 echo "<BR>";
 echo $row['PLACA'];

 $resultado[] = array(
 'nome_cliente' =>$row['NOME_CLIENTE'],
 'cpf' =>$cpf,
 'telefone' =>$row['TELEFONE'],
 'nome_veiculo' =>$row['NOME_VEICULO'],
 'placa' =>$row['PLACA'],
 );
}

echo(json_decode($resultado));
?>
```

nunca havia usado json, estou começando e estou bem perdido

Comment: o JSON retorna correto? Qual o problema que está apresentando?

Comment: O json está retornando correto, o que está acontecendo é que não consigo pegar o valor do array retornado por ele e atribuir a um elemente html

Comment: Se eu der um var_dump em $resultado, ele retorna isso

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["nome_cliente"]=> string(13) "JOÃO DA SILVA" ["cpf"]=> string(11) "25836914766" ["telefone"]=> string(11) "48997466427" ["nome_veiculo"]=> string(5) "Fusca" ["placa"]=> string(8) "abc-9809" } }

Comment: Então quer dizer que o array foi preenchido. O problema está em ele através do json ali no código jquery

Comment: da um `console.log(resultado)` pra ver sde o json esta chegando corretamente

Comment: não está chegando. Ele me retorna false

Answer (score -1):

Porque não tentas fazer da seguinte forma:

**Script:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("tr[data-toggle='modal']").click(function(){

        //Pegando valores dos campos "data-* do <tr> clicado"
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var data = $(this).data("data");
        var status = $(this).data("status");
        var problema = $(this).data("problema");
        var solucao = $(this).data("solucao");
        var carro = $(this).data("carro");
        var cpf = $(this).data("cpf");

        //requisição ajax para obter dados das tabelas "cliente" e "veículo"
        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../controller/php/carregar_dados_OS_Modal.php",
    data: { id: id, data: data, status: status, problema: problema, solucao: solucao, carro: carro, cpf: cpf },
    success: function (resultado) {
        console.log(resultado);  //para testar o que está a ser retornado na consola. 
   $("#nome_cliente").text(resultado.nome_cliente);

    //Atribuindo esses valores aos elementos do modal
       /* $("#id").text(resultado.id);
        $("#data").text("Emissão: "resultado.data);
        $("#status").val(resultado.status);
        $("#problema").text(resultado.problema);
        $("#solucao").text(resultado.solucao);*/

    }
});
    });
</script>
```

**PHP para trabalhar nos resultados que queres ir buscar a base de dados**

```
<?php
```

## Uma vez que fizemos uma chamada em metodo POST

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    $id_veiculo = $_POST['id'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

$conn = new Conexao();
$link = $conn->getLink();

$select = "SELECT veiculo.PLACA , veiculo.NOME as NOME_VEICULO,cliente.NOME as NOME_CLIENTE,cliente.TELEFONE FROM `veiculo` INNER join cliente on veiculo.CPF = cliente.CPF WHERE cliente.CPF =$cpf AND veiculo.ID_CARRO =$id_veiculo ";
$resultado_consulta = mysqli_query($link, $select);

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_consulta) )
{
 echo $row['NOME_CLIENTE'];
 echo "<BR>";
 echo $row['NOME_VEICULO'];
 echo "<BR>";
 echo $row['TELEFONE'];
 echo "<BR>";
 echo $row['PLACA'];

 $resultado = array(
 'nome_cliente' =>$row['NOME_CLIENTE'],
 'cpf' =>$cpf,
 'telefone' =>$row['TELEFONE'],
 'nome_veiculo' =>$row['NOME_VEICULO'],
 'placa' =>$row['PLACA']
 );
}

echo(json_decode($resultado));
}else{
    // Retorne o seu erro. 
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Bom, continua não funcionando. Descobri que o problema está em atribuir os valores para o array $resultado. Se dou um echo em alguma posição ele mostra como se fosse indefinida.